# How to join models in Python djangorestframework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to joint two models in django-rest-framework.
My code isn't throwing any error but also it isn't showing other model fields that need to be joined.

Below is my code snippet:

**Serializer:**

```
class CompaniesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Companies
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'category')

class JobhistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companies = CompaniesSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Jobhistory
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'company_id', 'companies')
```

**View** .

```
class UserJobs(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = JobhistorySerializer()

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        data = Jobhistory.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        return data
```

**model:**

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
   ordering = ('created',)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    title = self.title or False
    category = self.category or False
    super(Companies, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Jobhistory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Companies)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        company_id = self.company_id or False
        title = self.title or False

    super(Jobhistory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what fields are not displaying? the `company_id` or `companies`? And can you also add your `models.py` file?

Comment: I want all fields of companies model to be added in response.

Comment: I see, it will be very helpful to see your `models.py` file. I'm assuming that `Jobhistory` has a ForeignKey to `Companies`?

Comment: Add your models.py and views.py, for more clarification

Comment: mind if you could post your model too?

Comment: I might be missing something there as I am new for python. I have updated my question with model.py and views.py. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

In your views, you have

```
serializer_class = JobHistorySerializer()
```

Remove the parenthesis from this.

The reason for this is apparent in the [`GenericAPIView`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L105), specifically the `get_serializer()` and `get_serializer_class()` methods:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
    deserializing input, and for serializing output.
    """
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

def get_serializer_class(self):
    """
    Return the class to use for the serializer.
    Defaults to using `self.serializer_class`.
    You may want to override this if you need to provide different
    serializations depending on the incoming request.
    (Eg. admins get full serialization, others get basic serialization)
    """
    assert self.serializer_class is not None, (
        "'%s' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, "
        "or override the `get_serializer_class()` method."
        % self.__class__.__name__
    )

    return self.serializer_class
```

As you can see in `get_serializer`, it initializes that serializer class with args and kwargs that aren't provided in your view code.